# Is this as high quality a GIF I can produce from this MP4 using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using Powerpoint to create animations which I then export into a video and crop and convert to GIF using ffmpeg.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zl9ht7mluiim7a/cropped_vlans-3vlans-tag-untag.mp4?dl=1) is the (cropped) MP4 video, and this is the GIF I was able to produce:

[image]

To my (untrained) eye, it appears rather grainy, and not terribly smooth. I am wondering if there are options in ffmpeg I can be using thaat will give me a better quality GIF.

Here is the command I am using to crop:

```
ffmpeg -i in\vlans-3vlans-tag-untag.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1262:423:91:154" in\cropped_vlans-3vlans-tag-untag.mp4
```

Here are the two commands I am using to convert:

```
ffmpeg -y -vf fps=35,scale=896:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen out\PALETTE.png -i in\cropped_vlans-3vlans-tag-untag.mp4
ffmpeg -y -filter_complex "fps=35,scale=896:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" -i in\cropped_vlans-3vlans-tag-untag.mp4 -i out\PALETTE.png  out\vlans-3vlans-tag-untag.gif
```

I should say, I am not particularly talented with ffmpeg, I mostly put these commands together from googling and other posts on this site. So if any of the arguments I am using are making the conversion worse, I'd also be interested in hearing about it.

I tried the `-b 2048k` option, and I couldn't tell a difference in quality. In fact, when I ran a SHA256 hash on the output file with and without this option, the result was identical.

Comment: I find that ffmpeg does a fairly poor job with gifs. Have a look at gifsicle, I use it to compile my gifs and imagemagick to create the source gifs from pngs I export using ffmpeg. I find it produces higher quality, smaller results, at the expense of a bit more faffing around. http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/ and http://imagemagick.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separate cropping step is leading to a generational loss. You can combine that and see.

```
ffmpeg -i in\vlans-3vlans-tag-untag.mp4
       -vf "crop=1262:423:91:154,scale=896:-1:flags=lanczos,fps=35,palettegen"
       out\PALETTE.png

ffmpeg -i in\vlans-3vlans-tag-untag.mp4 -i out\PALETTE.png
       -filter_complex "[0]crop=1262:423:91:154,scale=896:-1:flags=lanczos,fps=35[v];
                        [v][1]paletteuse"
       out\vlans-3vlans-tag-untag.gif
```

Comment: Hrmm, I'm having a hard time seeing a difference. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BcKJT.gif) is the image the original way I did it, and [here](http://i.imgur.com/ogrEbwn.gif) it is using the combined crop/convert step.  The 2nd file is slightly smaller, I did notice. So at least that is an improvement.